# Kashrut with very costy salt?

Tags: history, kashrut-kosher, money, meat, salt

Currently the cost of the salt (for human consumption) is practically negligible, mostly around $1/kg.

But it wasn't always so. There were centuries as salt mining and selling was a governmental monopoly, and the government used it as some type of a "luxury tax" - similarly, as we can today see in the case of the benzine in some countries. This made salt prices irrationally high.

But making kosher meat requires a lot of salt.

What should be done, if a kg of salt would cost a hundred dollars?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, meat can be eaten raw (unsalted, unroasted, un-anything, straight from the carcass) after just rinsing it (YD 67:2).

Regarding salting, a non-trivial number of rabbinic authorities (even current ones) have allowed using sugar to 'salt' meat when salt was not an option (for availability or medical reasons). See [this article](http://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5138) for a sampling of sources.

There are two other ways though of permitting meat to be cooked which do not require salt: roasting (YD 76) and blanching (YD 67:6, 73:3). While roasting is still employed nowadays by all even [*lechatchila*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/759), many communities nowadays are accustomed to not blanch unsalted meat, though [*bedieved*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/759) or in certain pressing circumstances even some in those communities permit its use.

You should certainly speak with your rabbi before attempting any of these methods or if salt poses a health or financial risk to you.

Comment: I was just curious, but thank you!

Answer (score 10):

See [OU.org](https://oukosher.org/the-kosher-primer/) that broiling is an alternative method for Koshering meat.

> The Torah forbids the consumption of the blood of an animal. The two
>   accepted methods of extracting blood from meat, a process referred to
>   as “koshering”, are either salting or broiling.