# Transferring ma'aser sheini sanctity to sugar

Tags: maaser-tithes, agriculture

Various sites (eg [this one](https://en.toraland.org.il/beit-midrash/halachic-guides/mitzvot-of-the-land/pesach-biur-maaserot-and-viduy-maaserot-nissan-5779/)) claim that it's possible to transfer ma'aser sheini sanctity from coins to sugar. What is the source of this, and how does it work given that coins are supposed to be redeemed for food in Jerusalem?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57047/759

Comment: Is the question about destroying the food that is Kadosh by Kedusha of Maaser Sheni?

Comment: בזמן הזה אין לנו מצוה לאכול מעשר שני   See Chazon Ish Demai Siman 2 sayif 7 dibbur Hamatchil Tnana perek he mishna zayin. nowadays we have no Mitsva to food in Jerusalem because it's not possible.

Comment: @kouty I buy food in Jerusalem almost every day

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%92

Comment: @Josh K but you don't eat Maaser Sheni. Maaser Sheni have to be eaten betahara. We cannot be clean from tumeat met today because we have no Mey Chatat

Answer (score -1):

Mishna Maaser Sheni 5.7

> One who had produce **at this time** and the time of removal arrived:Bet Shammai says: he must exchange it for money. But Bet Hillel says: it is all the same whether it becomes money or it remains fruit.

Comment from Sefaria:

> But Bet Hillel says: it is all the same whether it becomes money or it remains fruit. Bet Hillel says it doesn’t matter whether the maaser sheni is produce or money, it must be removed at the end of the third or sixth year, **because it can’t be brought to Jerusalem when the Temple no longer stands**. So he should just leave the maaser sheni as produce and let it rot (see above 1:5).

The source is from the Rash who quotes Yerushalmi:

> וטעמא דב"ה מפרש בירושלמי (שם) אפי' מחללו מה מועיל אחד כסף ואחד פירות טעונין גניזה ומניח הפירות במקום המוצנע עד שירקבו:‏

To redeem a coin in fruits, Maaser Sheni 1.5

> One who bought produce unwittingly, the money must be restored to its former place. But if intentionally, the produce must be taken up and be consumed in the [holy] place, and when there is no Temple, it must be left to rot.

To buy a fruit unclean is prohibited. Maybe that nowadays that he needs the coin, the Bet Mikdash can be rebuilt, and he gives the Kedusha to a fruit not unclean and not able to be unclean (לא הוכשר לקבל טומאה), and that will not rot before the travel to Jerusalem (יכולים להגיע לירושלים) (The Bet Hamikdash can be rebuilt), there is no problem. For beet sugar, it's perhaps different because he is made using water and it's unclean (הוכשר לקבל טומאה). See [Poskim](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%) about this Problem.

Sugar is equivalent to fruits regarding the permission to buy it with a coin of Maaser Sheni, it is Gidule Karka, the Gemara in Eruvin learns it from a Drasha (Klal ufrat Uklal or Ribuy and Myut and Ribuy)The specificity of Sugar was (when it was produced from sugar cane) that it's not Muchshar to receive Uncleanness. Maaser Sheni have to be eaten in a state of purity. It's not possible nowadays because of tumeat met.

Comment: That says I can keep my ma’aser in the form of produce even if it rots. It doesn’t say I can transfer sanctity FROM coins TO produce.

Comment: I’m asking specifically for the source in which he said that it’s acceptable to transfer FROM coins TO produce in order to allow the produce to go to waste. That scenario is not at all covered by the passage you quoted, which relates to leaving it in the form of produce all along.

Comment: It also doesn’t mention sugar

Comment: Sugar is Gidule Karka.

Comment: If I find time I will search

Comment: I don’t specifically need it to be a source from him stating this, just the source of the apparent tradition that sugar is an acceptable way of disposing of monetary sheini.